# How to organize model class right way in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

newbie in Kotlin there
I have read the document about data class (model class as my understanding) at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html
And by this way, we can declare model class as below:

```
data class AModel(var title: String, var body: String)
```

Cool! It's so brief! So can I declare all model class in one file ? It's okay ? 
Example:

```
data class AModel(var title: String, var body: String)
data class BModel(var title: String, var body: String)
data class CModel(var title: String, var body: String)
data class DModel(var title: String, var body: String)
data class EModel(var title: String, var body: String)
```

As my idea, it's very easy to manage.
Do you think I should declare by this way? Positive and negative ? 
Thanks all!

Comment: If it's easiest for you, just do it! You can always break it up into multiple files later, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to know how every developer think about this, for my knowledge.